# Password validation numrows == 0 return true future issue?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, authentication, passwords

I am new to php and sql programming and creating a simple login and I have had issues with validating that a user is logged in. I have searched the web extensively for the past 2 days and I have fixed it, but I don't know if my fix will be problematic somehow in the future. And this is going to be a pretty important program, so i'd really like to know before running into a problem later.

Connecting to database works. Signup form works. Email activation works. And using the code below, the login seems to work - it only lets in emails and passwords logged in the database and passwords/emails that don't match don't log in, using `$p_hash = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` on the signup page for password hashing (from what I understand, this is safe). And then using the code below (along with some javascript/ajax verification) to validate the password with the email address. Using `$p = $_POST['p'];` and `!password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)`.

I mention that, because it seems to have been contributing to the problem here.

```
$p = $_POST['p'];

// GET USER IP ADDRESS
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
if($e == "" || $p == ""){
    echo "login_failed";
    exit();
} else {
// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $db_id = $row[0];
    $db_username = $row[1];
    $db_pass_str = $row[2];
    if(!password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else {
        // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
        exit();
    }
}
exit();
```

The code above includes check_login_status.php , so this lead me to find a problem in some check_login_status.php code. Where `if($numrows > 0)` before I changed it to the code below - where `if($numrows == 0)`

```
function evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$id,$u,$p){
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows == 0){ ////////THIS COULD BE PROBLEMATIC?, WORKS FOR NOW!!!!!!!
    return true;
}}
```

So, for some reason, it's showing that the number of rows in the database equals 0, which isn't true. It seems to be because of the password hashing because that was how I found this problem in the first place, and when I take out `AND password='$p'` and run the code with `if($numrows > 0)` then it works.

This modification (`if($numrows == 0)`) made the login verification work, but I don't want it to present a problem in the future.

Any help/comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your `evalLoggedUser()` function, you're passing in the plaintext password and using it in your query; but the password hash value stored in the database won't match the plaintext password, so it will never find any matching records

Comment: If you need the password check in this function, then eliminate the password check from the query, test for 1 row returned, fetch that row, and validate the password using password_verify() as you do in the login check

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker. I considered that before, but if that's the case then why would I be able to log in using the plain text password on the login page? From what I understand, `$p = $_POST['p'];` should pull the data from the password id in the form. Then `$db_pass_str = $row[2];` gets the password from the DB (3rd column). Then `if(!password_verify($p, $db_pass_str))` means if *form pw* != *db_pw* then login_failed. Isn't that right?

Comment: @MarkBaker i'm still thinking about and going to try what you've said in your second comment. Thanks again.

Comment: I've been trying to do what @MarkBaker said, but i'm still not getting much. I know that when I take out `AND password='$p'` that it finds a row which is what i want, but i'm fairly sure that `password` is the hashed password from the DB, because it is hashed in the DB. And i think that `password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)` is supposed to interpret the hashed pw and make sure it's the same as `$p`. Where `$p = $_POST['p'];`